# c# Custom Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I can't get my code (below) to execute the exceptions!

1. First, the bank account is empty.
2. 1500 deposit is made
3. Attempt to withdraw 1050 but the overdraft limit is 1000
4. Since the the amount to withdraw is greater than the overdraft limit the
   OverdraftEx exception should display my message (but it is not).
5. Then an attempt to withdraw 1000 which should be successful and the
   balance should become 500
6. Now, an attempt to withdraw 50 but second exception message DailyLimitEx should display which is exceeding the daily limit, because the Daily withdraw limit is 1000 and it has already been withdrawn for the day, again this exception is not getting displayed.
7. Then, End of the Day will display which is resetting the DailyLimit back to 0.
8. Then an attempt to withdraw 50 is allowed because it is a new day.

I can't get the exceptions' messages to display.
Can you please help? at the end there is a sample output.

Thanks

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Account account = new Account();
            try
            {
                double overdraftLimit = 1000;
                double dailyWithdrawlLimit = 1000;
            }
            catch (OverdraftEx e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
            }
            catch (DailyLimitEx e2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e2.Message);
            }

            account.display();
            account.deposit(1500);
            account.withdraw(1050);
            account.withdraw(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
            account.withdraw(50);
            account.endDay();
            account.withdraw(50);

            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
    }

    class OverdraftEx : Exception
    {
        private static string msg = " Sorry, the amount you are trying to withdraw exceeds your allowed overdraft limit.";
        public OverdraftEx() : base(msg)
        {
        }
    }

    class DailyLimitEx : Exception
    {
        private static string msg1 = " Sorry, you have exceeded your allowed daily withdrawal limit.";
        public DailyLimitEx() : base(msg1)
        {
        }
    }

    class Account
    {
        public int accountID { get; set; }
        public double amount;
        public double balance;
        public double Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return balance;
            }
            set
            {
                if (amount > overdraftLimit)
                {
                    OverdraftEx ex1 = new OverdraftEx();
                    throw ex1;
                }
            }
        }

        public double overdraftLimit { get; set; }

        public double dailyWithdrawlLimit
        {
            get
            {
                return dailyWithdrawlLimit;
            }
            set
            {
                if (amount > dailyWithdrawlLimit - 1000)
                {
                    DailyLimitEx ex2 = new DailyLimitEx();
                    throw ex2;
                }
            }
        }

        public Account()
        {
            accountID = 10;
            balance = 0;
            return;
        }

        public Account(int accID, double accBalance)
        {
            accountID = accID;
            balance = accBalance;
            return;
        }

        public void withdraw(double amount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(" Attempting to withdraw $" + Math.Round(amount, 2));
            balance = balance - amount;

            Console.WriteLine(" Account #: " + accountID);
            Console.WriteLine(" Your new balance is $" + Math.Round(balance, 2));
        }

        public void deposit(double amount)
        {
            // calculating the balance after depositing money

            if (amount > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Depositing $" + Math.Round(amount, 2));
                balance = balance + amount;
                Console.WriteLine(" Account #: " + accountID);
                Console.WriteLine(" Balance: $" + Math.Round(balance, 2));
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(" Sorry, amount is invalid");

            Console.WriteLine("");
            return;
        }

        public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(" Account ID: " + accountID);
            Console.WriteLine(" Balance: $" + Math.Round(balance, 2));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            return;
        }
        public void endDay()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(" End Day");
            Console.WriteLine(" Account ID: " + accountID);
            Console.WriteLine(" Balance: $" + Math.Round(balance, 2));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Sample output:
Note: the first error message in the sample output should display: "Sorry, the amount you are trying to withdraw exceeds your allowed overdraft limit" not what is displayed below.
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apPkj.png)

Comment: I recommend you take a step back and learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: You're only looking to catch an exception on these two lines of code: `double overdraftLimit = 1000; double dailyWithdrawlLimit = 1000;` There's no exception that will be thrown by assigning two `int`values to `double`s.

Comment: You need to re-evaluate how you are using properties and fields and what assignments are. Never in your property setters are you actually checking the `value` or assigning it. Your fields are also public. This question might be a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: Note that even when you fix the variable/field assignment issue in the Main method, your exceptions will still not be thrown. The exception throwing is part of the setters of the properties, yet your Account methods never invoke the property setters (i.e., never assign something to the respective properties), thus the exceptions will not be thrown since the exception-related code in the property setters is not executed. Not that the logic in the property setters makes much sense to begin with, as the value assigned to a property will just be ignored/discarded by the setters...

Comment: Also, the getter of your dailyWithdrawlLimit property will suffer a StackOverflow exception (no, i am not kidding). There is so much broken stuff in your code with respect to properties, i suggest you take a step back and spend some more time with C# tutorials covering how properties work and how they should/can be used...

Answer (score 0):

First: You do not use the correct Name in your methodes `withdraw()` and `deposit()`.
It should be `Balance = Balance - amount` and not `balance = balance - amount`.
Second: In the setter for `Balance` you do not work with the new value the setter is given. You can refer to the new value by the keyword `value`, also you do not update the backing field for your property.